# flutter pub get is stucking

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

When I run in terminal `flutter pub get` is stuck  it's showing

OS MacOS Catalina 10.15.3

```
Got TLS error trying to find package launch_review at https://pub.dartlang.org.                                    
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...                                           
Got socket error trying to find package launch_review at https://pub.dartlang.org.                                 
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...                                          
Got TLS error trying to find package launch_review at https://pub.dartlang.org.                                    
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...                                          
Got socket error trying to find package launch_review at https://pub.dartlang.org.                                 
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 4 in 8 seconds...                                          
Got socket error trying to find package launch_review at https://pub.dartlang.org.
```

Comment: Does ur pubspec.yaml end with exit code 0 when you remove launch review package

Comment: No I just terminated my command

Answer (score 9):

Quick fixes before explanation:

- Restart your router! Works for me several times.
- Make sure your network is not behind a proxy
- Make sure you can **ping** to **pub.dev** without any packet loss
- Try to close all of your dart.exe processes before retying to perform the **flutter pub get**
- Try to delete an existing package from your **pubspec.yaml** and re-get it to see if it works
- Try to [manually add the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491352/flutter-how-to-manually-install-packages) to your project

So, I had (and sometime still having) the same issue. I've analyzed it and came to a conclusion that the package download manager and the server that hosts those packages aren't reliabe at all. Very small packages might just successfully be imported with "flutter pub get", whereas big ones might last forever to download. This is definately a networking issue, on either yours or their side.

Just for verificatioin that we are indeed experiencing the same issue:

1. open your cmd (no matter t OS) and run: **ping -t pub.dev**  .Now, if you see those inconsitent replies from the server, it means there's something wrong with the network (yours or their side). This looks something like this:

   [image]
2. Open up your task manager and look for the latest dart.exe task (it should be invoked the moment you **flutter pub get**. This task is the package that is being downloaded. If you see the process size never exceeding a certain size, and the get command is still stuck, it only indicates a network issue and the package might never be downloaded successfully. For example, my attempts to get the carousela_flutter 1.4.1 package ended up with a halted process size of around 60mb, looks this this:

[image]

If you wait for a relatively large amount of time (10 minutes I would say is enough) and the connectivity issue is still not resolved, you will see the following msg from flutter:
"**Process finished with exit code 0**".

I suggest you try another time or [maually add the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491352/flutter-how-to-manually-install-packages).

p.s: it doesn't happen with all of the packages and from my investigation is seems to be related to the size of it. e.g, I managed to get the carousela_flutter 0.7.0 package, but the 1.4.1 failed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, The host of my ISP was blocked so it could not get the package and it was showing **pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...**

So I turn on my VPN and tried once again and this time it was a success

Answer (score 3):

If its a git error, use this command:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889129/12966479)

Answer (score 2):

502 Bad Gateway trying to find package package_name at https://pub.dartlang.org.
If you click on the link, you'll find that the website is down. The same is also applied to https://pub.dev/.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved it on my Windows machine.

After many tries from answers in many discussions out there, I tried a lot of stuff, like:

- **Restarting the machine**
- **Deleting the cache folder (the dart-sdk download may be restarted)**
- **Adding dart-sdk in the Environment Variable Path**

  X:\Dev\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\
- **Adding dart-sdk´s bin folder in the Path variable (for both Environment and User Variables) (desperate action, I know)**

  X:\Dev\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin

And still didn´t work.

BUT... I´ve found on [this thread](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1989) something about a proxy problem.

Then I´ve decided to try it out on my Windows machine, and it worked (finally).

Try typing this on Power Shell:

```
$Env:https_proxy="your.proxy.here:8080"
```

Then try `flutter doctor` again

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hmm, i know how frustrating it can be trying to solve the issue, the best solution to this is to use vpn and connect to another server. this way i was able to solve the problem without stress

Answer (score 1):

make sure there is no typo in `pubpspec.yaml` check it on here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72198419/8122500

Answer (score 0):

As said it might be something that has to do with your network....
Disconnecting and reconnecting fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no firewall is blocking it.

Check for Internet connectivity too. Search your browser, don't rely on the windows wifi symbol.

For me, KIS (Kaspersky) was blocking **pub.bat**.
If that is the case please also check---- Flutter, dart, android studio, Gradlew.bat, sdkmanager.bat, adb.exe, qemu-systems, emulator-check and google for any blockage. (just search in firewall settings).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was my virus program (AVG AntiVirus' Web Shield) that suddenly caused pub get to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Because restaurant depends on flutter any from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown SDK "flutter"), version solving failed

---

fix proplem
done
change this package
this path prev last
path_provider_windows:file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.0.5/lib/
change path fluatter plus /all
path
path_provider_windows:file:///C:/all/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.0.5/lib/
its ok
thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by using Visual Studio Debuggable Package Manager PowerShell, on your system open visual studio debuggable package manager and then type in flutter doctor it will resolve it within seconds