# Error message when press packages get in flutter

Tags: flutter

Because rabit depends on dev_dependencies any which doesn't exist (could not find package dev_dependencies at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 10 in 64 seconds...

that is the message that appears always i try to install dependencies

Comment: which lib can't solve?

Comment: i remove every library but the error persist

Comment: what command you using?

Comment: flutter packages get... but i press the button on android studio

Answer (score 2):

see if your pubspec.yaml is correctly indented, dev_dependencies: was in a wrong position with me, I just noticed it when I switched VSCode to Android Studio

Comment: this has worked for me, i didn't believe it at first, but I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i've run flutter docter -v and its all on checked green there is no problem. but i **solve** by check my `pubspec.yaml`

```
# these error
#  google_sign_
  in: ^5.0.4
```

yah i dont know i've enter my keyboard on there so the package cant find

```
# these solved
#  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
```