# Unable to create a flutter project

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a flutter project but it get failed. here is the flutter doctor response

[image]

and here is the snap of flutter create

[image]

i have window 8.1 pro installed in my laptop. Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This question has been asked here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879550/how-to-fix-httpexception-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-received

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136307/flutter-pub-get-is-stucking