# Prevent flutter pub get from retrying

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, github-actions, flutter-dependencies

Someone typed a private package url wrongly in pub spec yaml file.

As a result, pub get kept retrying but obviously never succeeded. This has wasted our github action build minutes.

How to prevent pub get from retrying after first failure?

```
get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 8 in 64 seconds...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter pub get is stucking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136307/flutter-pub-get-is-stucking)

Comment: No, this thread suggests solution to troubleshot why it's stuck. I know why mine is stuck. I just want to find a way to stop pub get from retrying

Comment: you can try with commenting package

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Our goal is not to make pub get just work. We fixed the typo and the private package worked. No need to remove it. Our goal is to prevent `pub get` to retry several time in the future in case something similar happen again because it just waste our build minute on Gitub Action CI (continuous integration)

Comment: Did it complete other tasks or was stuck at pub get?

Comment: Was stuck at pub get

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- name: run pub get
  run: flutter pub get
  timeout-minutes: 2
```

It should stop trying after 2 minutes

Comment: Tested but It is not working. This is telling github workflow that if the command run pub get fails, continue to the next step. But the command never fails, as it keeps retrying.

Comment: Edited my answer please check