# flutter pub get stuck

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Why is flutter pub get stucked in loading when I create a flutter project either in vs code or cmd. please help me, i'll attach the screenshot below.
[image: vs code]

[image: cmd]

i tried flutter clean but it didnt work. how can i resolve this problem? thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try doing the same but with a VPN?

Comment: try the methods in the following article. i was able to fix the problem by following them.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136307/flutter-pub-get-is-stucking