# Flutter giving pub get failed (server unavailable)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, google-apis-explorer

Got socket error trying to find package watcher at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Got socket error trying to find package watcher at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Got socket error trying to find package test at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...

Comment: You can check your internet connection for pc first. if its pinging correctly then it should work

Answer (score 1):

- Restart your router! Works for me several times.
- Make sure your network is not behind a proxy
- Make sure you can **ping** to **pub.dev** without any packet loss
- Try to close all of your dart.exe processes before retying to perform the **flutter pub get**
- Try to delete an existing package from your **pubspec.yaml** and re-get it to see if it works
- Try to [manually add the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491352/flutter-how-to-manually-install-packages) to your project